# AngularJS - Error: ng:areq - Bad Argument controller is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading the book Angularjs Essentials - http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23139559-angularjs-essentials

I'm trying to follow the code exmaples.

I have this plunker with the code I have

https://plnkr.co/edit/jFK3ooODMChtXJqO7syf?p=preview

locally in chrome I get the error

```
    Error: ng:areq
    Bad Argument

    Argument 'parkingCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I'm sure the problem is syntax in 'angular module' bit at the top of either controller.js, services.js or directive.js

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how the stop this error

Comment: You can check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues

(i) Change the references as below in plunker

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
```

(ii) No need to have dependencies injected for the service **`parkingService`**, change it as

```
angular.module('parking').factory("parkingService", function() {
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/wARo1AzPJEmo5RCrUN8r?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

When you define your service, you had recreated the app again with this syntax `angular.module('parking', [])` that's why the defined controller is no longer existing after this file loaded. So you can change this to `angular.module('parking')` as below in `services.js` file will fix the issue

```
angular.module('parking').factory("parkingService", function() {
    var _calculateTicket = function (car) {
        var departHour = new Date().getHours();
        var entranceHour = car.entrance.getHours();
        var parkingPeriod = departHour - entranceHour;
        var parkingPrice = parkingPeriod * 10;
        return {
            period: parkingPeriod,
            price: parkingPrice
        };
    };
    return {
        calculateTicket: _calculateTicket
    };
});
```